# How to create vertically nested scrollviews with viewpager content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-design-library

This is in a lot of apps, where there is header content a view pager and then the pager content.  The header content can scroll off the top then the pager content docks and continues to be able to scroll.  I've tried a couple ways of doing this, I had the most success with using NestedScrollView, but I was never able to get fling and a few other use cases working right.  As far as I can tell the apps that do this all spin their own solution.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to go about building this type of ui.  Below is Google+ which uses this ui.

[image: google exmaple]

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer (the question itself is quite open-ended) but I found cheesesquare implementation by Chris Banes (he's from the android team i think) very helpful with what you're asking.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: The existing apps definitely don't use this approach, I went down the route of a layout similar to https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml, but didn't have any luck.  I may have just not put enough time into it.

Answer (score 1):

What dejavu86 has said. The app in question is a demo of Design Support Library which has the UI widget, CollapsingToolbarLayout, which you are asking about.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html